# How to import a project into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, import, project

HI I am trying to import a project into eclipse. The process is that I right click on the package explorer tab and click import, then I navigate to the location of the project. It does not matter if I select copy into workspace or not, I am told that a project with the same name already exists. It does not. I have deleted it from the package explorer and from the workspace folder. Also, I have renamed the folder I am trying to import but still to no avail. It will not let me open the project in the workspace. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

It told you that the project with the same name already exists, but not "the folder name already exists".

The project name and the folder name are different.

To make sure your project name does not exists in the workspace, please open the `.project` file to see the project name.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this message many times, and red and tried to apply a lot of answers but one key thing has not been in any of them.

The most important thing is to **first** uncheck the "Copy projects into workspace" selectbox, and **then** you can browse for root directory or archive file, it does not matter. If you first click "Browse", unchecking "Copy projects into workspace" won't do any difference. Nor will refreshing of Package or Project Explorer, like it was explained in this question:[Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace error in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715403/some-projects-cannot-be-imported-because-they-already-exist-in-the-workspace-err)