# Project not opening in Eclipse after Eclipse reinsatlled

Tags: java, eclipse

I was developing some projects over eclipse, but my Eclipse crashed and I need to reinstall it. but how can I open my previous works as Project in Eclipse. I made it a zip file but its not working from Import.

Comment: In Import you can select "Existing Projects into Workspace" and then select the old workspace folder, there you will see your old projects and can import them into new eclipse.

Comment: Not able to select any of the options.

Comment: It says: "Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace"

Comment: Do you have some projects with same name as old ones in your current workspace? Also take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715403/some-projects-cannot-be-imported-because-they-already-exist-in-the-workspace-err

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `import`>`Existing Projects to Workspace`>`Select Root directory`

uncheck the "copy projects into workspace" selectbox, and then click "refresh" button, you will be able to import the project

A very common problem.