# import project from workspace in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

I have problem with importing projects from workspace into eclipse even though I am able to check the projects (which shows checkable).

After I hit the finish button, there is an error which says 
"Some projects can not be imported because they already exist in the workspace or their project description file is corrupt."

I have already deleted the projects from workspace so that let me be able to check from the import box.

So I guess that "project description file is corrupt" is the cause.

Can you help me out to fix it. I will appreciate it in advance.

Comment: The mentioned "project description file" is the file `.project` in the root of the project's directory. Could you please post its content?

Comment: Additionally, don't enable "copy project" when selecting import projects that are already in the workspace.

Comment: check this link hope will help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715403/some-projects-cannot-be-imported-because-they-already-exist-in-the-workspace-err

Comment: Thanks, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest start from scratch ,including choosing new location for Workspace.

If all of your old projects exist in a single directory or in a single parent directory, you can do File -> Import... -> Existing Projects into workspace. Choose a root directory that is a parent all of the projects you want to import. You will then be able to import  project/projects at once.

Comment: Suggesting a new workspace location seems to be too radical. Usually importing a single project should not require that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your workspace it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The below issue solved my issue:

- Navigate to your workspace.
- Copy the existing project you want to import somewhere else.
- Now import the existing project in the eclipse.
- It should look like below image after copying[image]