# Again, Eclipse says "some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace"

Tags: eclipse

I know this has been asked a lot before, but none of the answers I found helped me out. The box for copying projects is not checked and there are no hidden projects in Navigator view. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Sounds like you have projects with a directory, and those projects are already defined in the workspace. Or, you are doing import on the workspace directory and not the new project directory. Your question lacks enough information.

Comment: Let's start with: close Eclipse. Open up the directory/folder that the workspace is in. Look there. Are the projects already present?

Comment: Please tell us which import mechanism you're using. How are you getting to this message?

Comment: I'm inclined to vote to close as a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715403/some-projects-cannot-be-imported-because-they-already-exist-in-the-workspace-err. But I want to give you a chance to tell us how your situation differs from the scenarios discussed there. More details, please?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. Thanks for being willing to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace error in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715403/some-projects-cannot-be-imported-because-they-already-exist-in-the-workspace-err)

Answer (score 0):

**The below issue solved my issue:**

- Navigate to your workspace.
- Copy the existing project you want to import somewhere else.
- Now import the existing project in the eclipse.
- It should look like below image after copying[image]